# GitLab: Builds on protected branches slower than unprotected branches

Tags: c#, .net, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are running self-managed GitLab for our large monolith repo. We have 12 Gitlab Runners to compile across all branches.
We have unprotected development branches and protected branches for the main branch and versions.
We have observed that our build times for release builds vary greatly (from 45 to 90 minutes), even though there is no difference in the amount being compiled and packaged.
(That is our own .NET-Build-Tool, which does a bunch of different things to create a release package, including the main .NET Build)
There is some variation that can be explained by different physical machines hosting the Runner VMs, but the difference between slowest and fastest runner overall is less than the variation between the slowest and fastest build on an individual runner.
We have lots of info logging and the times scale pretty linearly across all actions performed, i.e. no single step of the build process is dragging the total time down.

We are grasping at straws here, but the only real pattern we can detect so far is that builds on protected branches (except for a handful of outliers in over 1600 builds that I've analyzed) are all slower than builds on unprotected branches.

Is there any possibility that this might actually be related? If so, what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have branch specific caches in your jobs?

Comment: Or, do you have some CI variables marked as protected that could affect the build process?

Comment: We have no protected CI Variables in the affected project.
There is only one difference between a release on a protected and a dev branch, one CLI option that is only used in the last step of the build process. We initialize release-builds via API and pass all options. The job definition is not different for dev/protected branches.